# Why do println statements in my custom Function's call method not appear in the logs?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

My method :-

```
private static Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, StreamDataWrapper> createFunction(){
    System.out.println("***** inside create function ******");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, StreamDataWrapper> function = new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, StreamDataWrapper>(){

        public StreamDataWrapper call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> c) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
            System.out.println("**** inside call of Function *******");
            System.out.println("**** Consumer record "+c);
            StreamData sd = mapper.readValue(c.value(), StreamData.class);
            System.out.println("**** StreamData "+sd);
            StreamDataWrapper sw = new StreamDataWrapper(sd);
            System.out.println("**** StreamDataWrapper "+sw);
            return sw;
        }

    };
    System.out.println("***** End of create function ******");
    return function;
}
```

I am calling this `createFunction()` from another method but the problem is it executing all the statements but not `statements inside call()`. Here is the `output` of my method.
O/P :-

```
***** inside create function ******
***** End of create function ******
```

Its not printing other output statements.
Following is the dependency I am using

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How and where do you use the `function` from `createFunction()`?

Comment: `JavaRDD<StreamDataWrapper> streamDataRdd = rdd.map(createFunction());`

Comment: And then? What's the action that is going to trigger your function's call?

Comment: actual process is after that using `CassadnraUtil` I am inserting data into DB, but its not inserting any data into DB, I have checked everything to identify the problem, initially I thought it was `cassandra` problem but its not that, later worked on `RDD`, finally I figure out the problem is with `call` method

Comment: _Show me the code please_ Can you just show the rows using `show` operator and put writing to Cassandra aside to make sure it does not contribute to the issue?

Comment: `CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(streamDataRdd).writerBuilder(KEYSPACE, CURL_TABLE_NAME,      CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(StreamDataWrapper.class, cols)).saveToCassandra();`

Comment: Can you replace `CassandraJavaUtil` with `streamDataRdd.foreach` to print the records to the console/stdout instead?

Comment: Here `streamDataRdd` which contains `StreamDataWrapper` object, not building this object, I mean I have print statements  inside the `constructor of StreamDataWrapper`which are not getting executed, so its not able to build the `object`, here the problem is not related to cassandra & its columns, because I used cassandra sessions to store the data in DB, it worked, but when I am trying this way, its not working, I have to make these statements to work now

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* that there might be two issues here:

1. `call` not printing out the messages
2. `call` is indeed called but you don't look at the right logs.

You do see some messages since pipelines with the function are instantiated (prepared for execution) but as you don't trigger any action you see no messages from inside. That would be the case 1.

As to the other possible issue I'd say that you look at wrong logs. You should look at the executor's logs where the function runs. That would be the case 2.

Comment: My interest is not to see logs, Its not executing the statements inside `call` method, those are the statements, which should executed. To test whether these statements are getting executed or not, I just put some `System.out.println()` statements. I observed that those statements are not executed, do you have any idea about how to make these statements(inside `call`) get executed?